# How to set Visio 2003 Trusted Locations

Tags: security, macros, microsoft-visio

I see the option in Visio 2003 to only trust macros stored in trusted locations, but I can't find any way to set up what these trusted locations are.

My problem is I have a template file that's not signed in the VBA project but the VBA project is locked (so I can't just sign it myself).

So, there are only two ways I can stop the warning:

1. lower my security settings so anything with macros will run (not a good idea)
2. Tell Visio that the template is in a trusted location (if this is even possible)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Microsoft article [Modify the list of trusted sources for macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/HP850528521033.aspx) covers the Visio scenario you describe.

Comment: That list is for trusted sources, not trusted locations.  My problem is I have a template file that's not signed but the VBA project is locked, so there are only two ways I can stop this: 1, lower my security settings so anything with macros will run, or two, tell Visio that the template is in a trusted location.